# Problem: "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"?

Tags: asp.net, database, visual-studio-2013, ms-access-2010, reporting

I'm facing this problem while executing my web site with asp.net in Visual Studio 2013 x64bit .. I can't connect my Database access to get data.

[image]

I'm blocked!

Comment: the problem was that my database extension isn't compatible with my office version .. I converted .accdb to .mdb and it works thank u :)

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the error The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. This error occurs when you try to make use of Excel 2007 or higher or Access 2007 or higher files using OLEDB connection in C# or VB.Net.

This happens only for Office 2007 or higher as it requires use of OLEDB ACE drivers for connection which do not come by default in Windows and hence we need to install them in order to get rid of this error.

**Downloading the Office System Drivers**

You need to visit the following download link for downloading 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=23734

I am not sure but these drivers seems to me of 32 BIT (x86) architecture and will work for most of you. In case you still get errors I would suggest to download the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable using the following download link.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Once you click Download it will prompt you to select the architecture i.e. 32 BIT (x86) or 64 BIT (x64).

Now here I selected 64 BIT (x64) as my system is 64 BIT but after installing it I was still getting the same error. Hence I decided to further investigate and found that my Visual Studio 2010 is of 32 BIT (x86) architecture from the task manager. The below screenshot displays the file devevn.exe*32.[image]

Reference by:http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/The-MicrosoftACEOLEDB120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine.aspx

Comment: Thank u .. I see that I have to Install VS2013 x64bit .. I will try this solution then reply to u the result :)

Comment: just remember me in your prayer

Comment: vakeel .. I didn't get a result .. I still have the same problem ! :'( .. but I will remember u in my prayer ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the cpu target to x86.

In VS right click your project solution then hit properties and go for the debug tab, on platform destiny select x86, save and generate your project.

Comment: But I have to use x64 because of my windows x64

Comment: Ok but, may be the MS Access that you have installed on your pc it's for x86 platform, if so, try my hint.

Comment: I'm already using Ms Access x64 :'(

Comment: Try out the hint above by @vakeel

Comment: Yes yes  I will try .. thank u all (y)